# RavenDB Query Aggregate Properties in Map/Reduce Index

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, ravendb, document-database

I have a map/reduce index that looks like this (as defined on the server).

Map:

```
from request in docs.Master_Requests
    select new
    {
        DocumentID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Year = request.Timestamp.Year,
        Month = request.Timestamp.Month,
        Day = request.Timestamp.Day,
        Hour = request.Timestamp.Hour,
        Minute = request.Timestamp.Minute,
        RequestBytes = request.RequestBytes,
        ResponseBytes = request.ResponseBytes,
        TotalRequests = 1
    }
```

Reduce:

```
from result in results
group result by new { result.Year, result.Month, result.Day, result.Hour, result.Minute }
    into g
    select new
    {
       DocumentID = Guid.NewGuid(),
       Year = g.Key.Year,
       Month = g.Key.Month,
       Day = g.Key.Day,
       Hour = g.Key.Hour,
       Minute = g.Key.Minute,
       RequestBytes = g.Sum(r => r.RequestBytes),
       ResponseBytes = g.Sum(r => r.ResponseBytes),
       TotalRequests = g.Sum(r => r.TotalRequests)
    }
```

I'm trying to query on the results of the map/reduce index like so:

```
session.Query<UsageAggregate>("RequestAggregateByMinute", true)
                                .Where(a => a.TotalRequests >= 1);
```

However, I am getting no results back when there are many results (as shown in the studio) that have a TotalRequests property greater than 1. I get results when I don't include a where predicate and I also get results when I filter on any other property than the aggregated properties (RequestBytes, ResponseBytes, and TotalRequests).

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A bit more information. It appears that I just can't do a range query on the aggregated fields (e.g. greater than doesn't work, equals works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. For whatever reason, I needed to cast the result of the Sum() like so. This must have to do with the dynamic compilation once it's sent to the raven server.

```
from result in results
group result by new { result.Year, result.Month, result.Day, result.Hour, result.Minute }
    into g
    select new
    {
       DocumentID = Guid.NewGuid(),
       Year = g.Key.Year,
       Month = g.Key.Month,
       Day = g.Key.Day,
       Hour = g.Key.Hour,
       Minute = g.Key.Minute,
       RequestBytes = (Int32)g.Sum(r => r.RequestBytes),
       ResponseBytes = (Int32)g.Sum(r => r.ResponseBytes),
       TotalRequests = (Int32)g.Sum(r => r.TotalRequests)
    }
```